# Is it normal for collard greens to be red?

Tags: ingredient-selection, greens

The collard greens that I have received are red. Is this normal/healthy? Image attached.

[image: Red Collard Greens]

Google searching this gives me zero results that are anywhere near relevant. I also can't find any images of red collard greens, they are always green in the image search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not normal for collards. Enlarging the picture, the discoloration looks to be a brownish-red. Those leaves look to be very old and quite possibly have been frozen (while still in the field), especially the one on the right. I would be tossing those.

Comment: Excuse the cheap shot: They aren't called collard reds for a reason :)

Comment: @rackandboneman yeah, like Roquefort isn't called a _blue cheese_ for a reason. ...wait...

Answer (score 0):

Ours are red too.  Green toward the middle/newer part of plant and more red on the lower leaves and tips of green leaves.  Usually, they get better with cold (live in SC), especially if it snows - makes them sweet.

This year it may be a couple reasons. One is variety. This year we have Georgua collards.  Past years have been a 'blue' variety. This years variety seems to have more red as the season progresses, but only I  certain beds. Other beds they're still green all around; this leads me to suspect alkalinity. The red ones are in beds where the soil more neutral or alkaline, the green ones are in more acidic soil.